# Mongo - non yaml config format to specify mmapv1 engine?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo 3.4.7. My mongodb.conf file is in the format of `foo = bar` and not yaml.

I need to switch the engine to mmapv1 because I like to use ext4 filesystem.

Does anyone know the default config for this in the format of 'foo = bar` instead of yaml?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use ext4 and this drives the decision to use MMAPv1? Note that the WiredTiger storage engine is a much more modern engine. It may be worth switching to XFS for WiredTiger alone. Note that you can use WiredTiger with ext4, it's just that the performance would be better using XFS.

Comment: This is just for development, so ext4 it is.

Answer (score 1):

The old style config file format is still supported as of MongoDB 3.6.3 for backward compatibility purposes.

However, support for this configuration style may not be around forever, and may be removed in the future. This old config file format dated from MongoDB 2.4, so the [description of the format](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/) will be outdated and some options doesn't apply anymore for newer MongoDB versions.

Thus, it's recommended to use the new YAML style format, and convert your old style config to YAML. See [Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) for details on the YAML style config.

Comment: is there a way to easily convert? that is alot to manually re-write in the default config

Comment: Not that I know of. How big is your config file?

Comment: to big to redo by hand. Using the deprecated syntax, how  do I specify the engine?

Comment: You can add `storageEngine = wiredTiger` in your config file. Please be aware that depreciation means that it may not behave as intended, as the format dated from MongoDB 2.4 where there is no storage engine support, so use at your own risk.